# Sending bulk messages in Powerbuilder

Tags: sms, powerbuilder

is sending bulk messages through a Powerbuilder app using comm ports possible? I want my Powerbuilder app to instruct a mobile phone connected though a comm port via bluetooth to send bulk messages to other phones or if possible by using the free text messaging sites on the web. And if it is, could you please lead me to an article or site on how how to do it? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Could you be a little more precise on what you intend to perform? You want to make serial communication with PB?

Answer (score 3):

You can use FileOpen, FileWrite, FileClose with the com port. For FileOpen, pass "\.\COM##" for the filename where ## is the com port number.